# Mandrill Integration in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mandrill

I want to send email through Mandrill. How to do this in .Net?

Does any one have sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a wrapper for .Net like https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet. Install library: Install-Package Mandrill

And do something like this:

```
        MandrillApi api = new MandrillApi(MandrillKey);

        // Set email or list of emails
        var listEmails = new List<EmailAddress>() { new EmailAddress("email@example.com", "User name", "to")};

        // Build email to be sent
        EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage()
        {
            To = listEmails,
            FromEmail = FromEmail,
            FromName = FromName,
            Subject = "Subject of email",
            Text = "Message of email",
        };

        // Creates messsage request based on email messasge
        SendMessageRequest emailRequest = new SendMessageRequest(emailMessage);

        // Get email results 
        List<EmailResult> emailResult = await api.SendMessage(emailRequest);

        // Loop results 
        foreach (var emailRes in emailResult)
        {
            if (emailRes.Status == EmailResultStatus.Sent)
            {
                // email sent
            }
            else
            {
                // email not sent
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but still did not get my solution

Comment: could you post the code you are trying with, so I can provide more help.